# surfaceView class crashing when exiting activity, Android

Tags: android, camera, surfaceview

surfaceView class crashes when I use an intent to leave the activity to go to another activity.  how can I leave this activity for another activity without having it crash?

I use this intent to leave this class and open another activity called the CameraView class:

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, CameraView.class);
  startActivity(intent);
```

stacktrace from LogCat:

```
04-08 21:42:46.620: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(25016): finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
04-08 21:42:46.630: E/SurfaceView(25016): NullPointerException while updating window.
mSession = android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy@41739aa8, mWindow = android.view.SurfaceView$MyWindow@41743978
04-08 21:42:46.630: E/SurfaceView(25016): Unexpected NullPointerException.
04-08 21:42:46.630: D/AndroidRuntime(25016): Shutting down VM
04-08 21:42:46.630: W/dalvikvm(25016): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40aca9d8)
04-08 21:42:46.640: E/AndroidRuntime(25016): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-08 21:42:46.640: E/AndroidRuntime(25016): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-08 21:42:46.640: E/AndroidRuntime(25016):    at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:578)
04-08 21:42:46.640: E/AndroidRuntime(25016):    at android.view.SurfaceView.onWindowVisibilityChanged(SurfaceView.java:226)
```

surfaceView activity code:

```
 class Preview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
        SurfaceHolder mHolder;
        DrawOnTop mDrawOnTop;


        Preview(Context context, DrawOnTop drawOnTop) {
            super(context);

            mDrawOnTop = drawOnTop;
            mFinished = false;

            // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
            // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
            mHolder = getHolder();
            mHolder.addCallback(this);
            mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        }

        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

            try {
               mCamera = Camera.open();
               mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
               mCamera.startPreview();

               // Preview callback used whenever new viewfinder frame is available
               mCamera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {
                  public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera)
                  {
                      if ( (mDrawOnTop == null) || mFinished )
                          return;

                      if (mDrawOnTop.mBitmap == null)
                      {
                          // Initialize the draw-on-top companion
                          Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
                          mDrawOnTop.mImageWidth = params.getPreviewSize().width;
                          mDrawOnTop.mImageHeight = params.getPreviewSize().height;
                          mDrawOnTop.mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mDrawOnTop.mImageWidth, 
                          mDrawOnTop.mImageHeight, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
                          mDrawOnTop.mRGBData = new int[mDrawOnTop.mImageWidth * mDrawOnTop.mImageHeight]; 
                          mDrawOnTop.mYUVData = new byte[data.length];                    
                      }

                      // Pass YUV data to draw-on-top companion
                      System.arraycopy(data, 0, mDrawOnTop.mYUVData, 0, data.length);
                      mDrawOnTop.invalidate();
                  }
               });
            } 
            catch (IOException exception) {
                mFinished = true;
                mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
                mCamera.stopPreview();
                mCamera.release();
                mCamera = null;
            }
        }

        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the preview.
            // Because the CameraDevice object is not a shared resource, it's very
            // important to release it when the activity is paused.
            mFinished = true;
            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;

        }

        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
            // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and begin
            // the preview.
            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            parameters.setPreviewSize(320, 240);
            parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(15);
            parameters.setSceneMode(Camera.Parameters.SCENE_MODE_NIGHT);
            parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        }

    } // end surfaceview
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

found out the answer that worked was to put System.exit(0) in the onPause method. that fixed all problems and the app reliable and 100% stable.  no crashing any more when exiting the Activity.

putting finish() in the onPause method did not work and the app continued to crash at random times after exiting the activity with the surface view.

one thing that did help reduce crashing earlier was to change the positions of stopPreview() and setpreviewCalback(null).  and also removing setpreviewcallback(null).  these modifications when called before exiting the activity with an intent reduced the number of crashes.

Comment: What? `System.exit()`? Seriously?!?

Comment: Never use System.exit(). See how the lifecycle of the activity affects your camera flow. Read the documentation for the camera for knowing when to call startPreview(), stopPreview() and when to release camera resources.

Answer (score 0):

Try first calling `stopPreview()` and only then `setPreviewCallback(null)`